# How can i minimise run time of fetching location details?

Tags: laravel, geolocation, geoip

I am using GEOIP plugin in my laravel system. All things are correctly working but response time of GEOIP is very more. I want to reduec it.

I tried to fetch simple IP address but it is not worked , because i need to do country validation also.

```
use \Torann\GeoIP\Facades\GeoIP;
$respondentLocation = GeoIP::getLocation();
```

I just need quick response nothing else.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that particular library but I'm assuming its looking up remote data (hence the speed issues). If so, there isn't a lot you can do outside of caching records, and possibly pre-fetching data (if your scenario allows for that).

Looking at their docs, it appears they do have caching mechanisms in place: http://lyften.com/projects/laravel-geoip/doc/commands.html